# Как создать дочернюю тему для WordPress, чтобы была возможность изменять подпапки

Tags: wordpress

Я понял, как сделать дочернюю тему и изменять файлы в родительской папке. Но как сделать так, чтобы была возможность менять файлы, которые находятся в подпапках?

Пробовал создавать ту же структуру файлов в директории дочерней темы, как и в директории родительской и использовать в ней строку:

`@import url("../../../aqeeq-agency/assets/css/bootstrap.css");`

Иметь возможность изменять файлы в дочерней теме мне нужно, чтобы иметь возможность впоследствии обновлять тему.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых подключение стилей через `@import url` - [плохой вариант](https://wp-kama.ru/id_8432/alternativa-import-v-dochernih-wordpress-temah.html). Нужно делать через `wp_enqueue_style()`.

*А ещё лучше для создания дочки использовать специальные плагины. Например [CTC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/). Тогда и дочка будет сделана правильно и настройки можно будет перенести корректно. Есть и другие приятные плюшки.

А после создания и настройки дочки плагин можно удалить.*

Во вторых дочерняя тема видит только [шаблоны](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2), файл функций и syle.css. Поэтому подключение других файлов нужно производить в файле функций или шаблонах. Способ подключения зависит от назначения подключаемых файлов. Например "запчасти" шаблона лучше подключать с пом. [get_template_part()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part). Скрипты и стили через `wp_enqueue_script()` `wp_enqueue_style()` соответственно.